# Anyway way to make a Matlab line object movable without much code?

Tags: matlab

In a Figure, I created a line object using the line command.  It cannot be dragged around.  I then used the GUI to insert a line, which yielded a lineshape object.  I can drag that around.  It's not as convenient because I have code that generates many line objects depending on the vertics of the selected shapes and line objects.  Better to be able to drag around the code-generated line objects than to have to manually insert many lineshape objects just so that I can drag them around.  Making the manually inserted lineshapes even less appealing is the fact that I'll draw them not perfectly vertically, then I have to go in to piddle with the 'X' field values to make it perfectly vertical.

Is there a programmatic way to convert a line object into a lineshape object?  I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve a lot of code.

Comment: What is a 'lineshape' object?

Comment: See also: [`draggable`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4179-draggable)

Comment: If I use Figure menus to Insert a Line, the Type field of the object is lineshape.  Maybe it's an internal undocumented class.  I appreciate your link to draggable.  Will take look-see.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to excaza for pointing me to the `draggable` solution. Note that a Figure's `Edit plot` mode must deactivated in order for the designated objects to be draggable.

For me, this is a much better alternative than using the Figure's native `Insert Line` object, which is inherently movable, but which also poses challenges if you need to use coordinates of the end points. Basically, the queried `X` property values seem to be in terms of the axes `normalized` axes `Units` rather than on the scale of the x-axis itself (as defined by `xlim`).

I also found a curiosity -- the Insert Line object doesn't have an `XData` property, though all other objects that I've dealt with do, i.e., objects resulting from the line command, and patches.  However, all these latter objects *also* return values for get(handle,`X`), and the values match those in `XData`. Until I found this, I thought that `X` might be for normalized coordinates, while `XData` might be for coordinates in terms of the `xlim` and `ylim` range for the axes.

Finally, another interesting detail is that the line objects are children of the figure rather than the axes. When they are selected, they don't show up in `findall(gco(gca),'Selected','on')`, but they do show up in `findall(gco(gcf),'Selected','on')`.  Odd, since their coordinates are with respect to the axes. I wonder how line objects on different axes are distinguished if they have the same coordinates.